# Android rawQuery - Is there a way to use parametrized "IN" for a collection of data

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I am trying to use dynamically created list in WHERE, for example:

```
select * from books where id in (123, 120, 125) and bookCover = 'Hardcover'
```

I want to use it with rawQuery and I have prepared SQL in "?" form, for example:

```
select * from books here id in (?) and bookCover = ?
```

is there any way, how to put a list of "ids" in the IN clause of the select? or do I have to forget about prepared statements with "?" ?

Thanks in advance for any help. Searched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - I do NOT know ANY DB (like Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, Postgres etc.) which provides for what you ask...

The nearest solution you can get is to insert the IDs into a second table and then use a subquery in the `IN` part...

`MyIDTable` hat 2 fields `QNO` (is just a key) and `ID` (contains the IDs you want in your `IN`... you first insert 3 rows with the same QNO and the respective IDs...

```
INSERT INTO MyIDTable (QNO, ID) VALUES (3, 120);
INSERT INTO MyIDTable (QNO, ID) VALUES (3, 123);
INSERT INTO MyIDTable (QNO, ID) VALUES (3, 125);
```

Then you can do a `SELECT` like this:

```
select * from books where id in (SELECT T.ID FROM MyIDTable T WHERE T.QNO = 3) and
bookCover = 'Hardcover'
```

Which basically allows for this:

```
select * from books where id in (SELECT T.ID FROM MyIDTable T WHERE T.QNO = ?) and
bookCover = ?
```

After you are done looking for that specific set of IDs you can clean up by `DELETE FROM MyIDTable WHERE QNO = 3`.

Comment: Hmm, i was affraid that that will be the answer. I know, it can be done in native query in hibernate, but... Well, this is not that case :-(

Comment: @premma hibernate does behind the scenes basically what I describe above (since no DB engine I know of supports this natively).

Comment: Thank you.. I was expecting this answer, but I wanted to be sure. The hint you gave me is helpful, i will think about that. Thank you once again for your quick answer.